# Lodash union won't work with the spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am using lodash and it's union function. But when I use a spread operator within union I am no longer getting the normal, expected result. What am I doing wrong and why won't lodash work with the spread operator? Thanks!

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

y = [3, 5]

normalResult = _.union(x, y)
unexpectedResult = _.union(...x, y)

// normalResult = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// unexpectedResult = [3, 5]
```

Comment: But, the spread is executing the function `union` as follow: `_.union(1, 2, 3, 4, [3, 5])`.  Did you know that?

Comment: Their [doc](https://lodash.com/docs/#union) says: _..Creates an array of unique values, in order, **from all given arrays** using **SameValueZero for equality comparisons**..._ `...x` basically turning the array to comma separated values..

Comment: Thanks, this helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.union` expects each argument to be an array. When you use `...x` you're spreading the array into separate arguments, which is not what it wants.

The spread operator would be useful if you had a 2-dimensional array and you wanted to merge each of the contained arrays with `_.union`, e.g.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 5]
a = [x, y];
result = _.union(...a);
```